# Hover text over post image on mouseover

Tags: wordpress, image, css, mousehover

I'm working on redesigning a blog in wordpress using the Genesis framework. This is probably the simplest thing ever, but I can't find a good solution to this.

The blog has a home page that shows post excerpts with images. The images link to the full post (it's not a featured image). What I want is for a "read more" text to appear on the post image on mouseover and that it links to the full post. I've found these effects for images that you add manually with html, but how do you add these effects for post images only?

Ideally I would love one of the amazing hover effects made by codrops (demo here: http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/index.html), especially Bubba.

But right now I've been searching for a solution for this for so long that I'm going to take what I get.

Kind regards,
moiety

```
figure.effect-bubba {
    background: #9e5406;
}

figure.effect-bubba img {
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-bubba:hover img {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

figure.effect-bubba figcaption::before,
figure.effect-bubba figcaption::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-bubba figcaption::before {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
    transform: scale(0,1);
}

figure.effect-bubba figcaption::after {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,0);
    transform: scale(1,0);
}

figure.effect-bubba h2 {
    padding-top: 30%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-20px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-20px,0);
}

figure.effect-bubba p {
    padding: 20px 2.5em;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,20px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,20px,0);
}

figure.effect-bubba:hover figcaption::before,
figure.effect-bubba:hover figcaption::after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

figure.effect-bubba:hover h2,
figure.effect-bubba:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) simply download this example.
2) set script and styles in your directory of js and css.
3) include them in your script.
4) compare your image html with this examples images.
5) put classes and elements like example images.

and you are simple able to get iffect like this.

please note it is not only magic of css, there is a js also take part in your Desiree effect.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. I did download the source, but there is no .js file. This is a css hover effect.

Comment: will you please give me your project link .. i will check it for you.